# Creating a simple MIDI plugin system with DryWetMidi

Tags: midi

I wrote a small WPF app to route MIDI in to MIDI out and send bank and program change messages to my older synth module. I decided to use DryWetMidi for the MIDI I/O, which is very easy to use. While reading the docs for DryWetMidi, I noticed it had support for high precision timing. I'm wondering if these timers could be used to create arpeggiators and other such MIDI effects.  Would this be as simple as processing MIDI data in the timer callback? What would be the best way to achieve something like this using this API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) (DWM). Yes, you can use [HighPrecisionTickGenerator](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia.HighPrecisionTickGenerator.html) separately from other DWM API:

```cs
var tickGenerator = new HighPrecisionTickGenerator();
tickGenerator.TickGenerated += OnTickGenerated;

tickGenerator.TryStart(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));

...

private void OnTickGenerated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It seems like most of the members of HighPrecisionTickGenerator are protected...

Comment: Can you please [create new issue](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/issues/new) so we can discuss a solution and try to make changes in API to solve your task?

Comment: I've closed [the issue](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/issues/102) since there is no info about the problem there.